# CPTScatterPlotInterpolationCurved Type not working Correctly

Tags: ios, iphone, core-plot, scatter-plot

I am using Coreplot Framework to create line graph,

```
 CPTScatterPlot *plot = [[CPTScatterPlot alloc] init];
 plot.dataSource = self;
 plot.identifier = @"mainplot";
 plot.dataLineStyle = lineStyle_;
 plot.plotSymbol = plotSymbol;
 plot.interpolation = CPTScatterPlotInterpolationCurved;
 [self.graph addPlot:plot];
```

if i'm use `CPTScatterPlotInterpolationLinear` the points are joined correctly in graph but `CPTScatterPlotInterpolationCurved` the points are not set correctly in graph

1.using  **CPTScatterPlotInterpolationLinear** [image: CPTScatterPlotInterpolationLinear]

2.using **CPTScatterPlotInterpolationCurved**
[image]

the top points are working correctly,only the bottom points not set properly,see points { (2,0),(3,0)},how to fix this issue ?

Comment: +1, this can lead to extreme overshot if 2 neighbour values have a large difference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is working as designed. The goal is get a smooth curve passing through all of the data points with as few abrupt changes in direction as possible.

If you have suggestions on how to improve it, please open an enhancement request on the Core Plot [issue tracker](https://code.google.com/p/core-plot/issues/list).